# 3angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot set property 'contract' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function loadAll() {
            Organization.query({`enter code here`
                page: pagingParams.page - 1,
                size: vm.itemsPerPage,
                sort: sort(),
                mapperType: 'NORMAL',
                status: 'DISABLED',
                search: vm.search
            }, onSuccess, onError);

        function sort() {
            var result = [vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
            if (vm.predicate !== 'id') {
                result.push('id');
            }
            return result;
        }

        function onSuccess(data, headers) {
            vm.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
            vm.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
            vm.queryCount = vm.totalItems;
            vm.page = pagingParams.page;
            vm.searchParams = PrmJson.fromJson(pagingParams.search);
            // vm.organizations = data;
            vm.organizations = getContractStatus(data);
        }

        function onError(error) {
            AlertService.error(error.data.message);
        }
    }

    function getContractStatus(organizations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < organizations.length; i++) {
            Contract.getByOrganizationId({
                    organizationId: organizations[i].id
                }, function (data) {
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        organizations[i]["contract"] = {id: 0};
                    } else {
                        organizations[i]["contract"] = {id: data.id};
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        return organizations;
    }
```

When I run the code above I get the following error message:

> angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot set property 'contract' of undefined

Comment: That means `organizations[i]` is undefined. Can you check the content of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing anonymous function, so there `data` and `i` value both are undefined .

```
function(data,i) {
  if (data.length == 0) {
    organizations[i]["contract"] = {
      id: 0
    };
  } else {
    organizations[i]["contract"] = {
      id: data.id
    };
  }
}(data,i);
```

**Demo**

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  demo1(i, function(k,l) {
    console.log('annonymous',l)
  }(i,i));
}

function demo1(val) {
  console.log('demo1',val)
}
```